# Swift 3, передача данных на сервер

Tags: ios, swift3

Занимаюсь разработкой приложения на iOS.
Необходимо по нажатию на UISwitch по tcp сокету передавать переменную на сервер.

Подскажите, как это осуществляется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала необходимо связать действие UISwitch с вызовом конкретного метода. Создайте в своём ViewController (или другом классе, в котором держите outlet'ы) outlet для UISwitch, и action-метод, который будет вызываться при сдвиге UISwitch:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet var switch : UISwitch!
  @IBAction func switchMoved(sender: UISwitch) {
    // далее здесь будет код
  }
}
```

Затем outlet и action-метод нужно связать с конкретным UISwitch, определённом в .xib-файле, Storyboard-файле или через код. Связывание проводится через Interface Builder или же тоже через код. Подробнее о связывании можно прочитать во View Programming Guide в документации.

Теперь конкретно о передаче переменной через сокет. Здесь стоит уточнить, какой сокет имеется в виду, и нужен ли сокет вообще (для простой передачи данных стоит воспользоваться более высокоуровневыми инструментами). Конкретно сокетов в Cocoa Touch нет, но можно воспользоваться потоками:

```
// hostname для подключения
let address = "127.0.0.1"
// удаленный порт
let port = 80
// выходной поток, куда будут писаться сырые данные
var outputStream: OutputStream? 
// создание потока (обертки над сокетом)
Stream.getStreamsToHost(withName: address, port: port,
  inputStream: nil, outputStream: &outputStream)
// открытие потока (одновременно будет установлено соединение через сокет)
outputStream?.open()
// пусть buffer - массив значений типа UInt8, наши данные
// отправка
outputStream.write(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
```

Если уровень абстракции OutputStream для вас слишком высок, можете посмотреть в сторону сокетов CoreFoundation, CFNetwork или даже POSIX-сокетов (ниже некуда). Для всех этих трёх случаев придётся иметь дело с unmanaged-кодом, и проще будет написать эти компоненты на Objective-C или просто C.

Comment: Выдает ошибку на строку Stream.getStreamsToHost(withName: address, port: port, inputStream: nil, outputStream: &outputStream). -- "Expected declaration". Надо что-то подключать для использования stream?

Comment: @pltsh_ Ничего не надо подключать, только что проверил у себя, XCode 8.3.3, macOS 10.12.6